# Create List of Functions using Piecewise

Tags: piecewise

It sometimes is useful to combine such expressions as

```
z1[t_] = Piecewise[{{Sin[t], Sin[t] > Cos[t]}}]
z2[t_] = Piecewise[{{Cos[t], Sin[t] > Cos[t]}}]
```

into something like

```
{z1[t_], z2[t_]} = Piecewise[{{{Sin[t], Cos[t]}, Sin[t] > Cos[t]}}]
```

especially when the `List` of `zi` is large, and the `Piecewise` conditions are many and expensive to evaluate.  However, the expression immediately above yields the error message

```
Set::shape: Lists {z1[t_],z2[t_]} and Piecewise[{{{Sin[t], Cos[t]}, Sin[t] > Cos[t]}}, 0] are not the same shape. >>
```

(The same error occurs with `Set` replaced by `SetDelayed` and for similar `If` statements.)

The following does work but seems cumbersome.

```
{z1[t_], z2[t_]} = Module[{tst = Sin[t] > Cos[t]}, 
    {Piecewise[{{Sin[t], tst}}], Piecewise[{{Cos[t], tst}}]}]
```

Is there a better approach that is extendable to a large number of `zi` and `Piecewise` conditions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your goal is to reduce typing, you could try something like

```
{z1[t_], z2[t_]} =
  With[{u = Sin[t] > Cos[t]}, Piecewise[{{#, u}}]]& /@ {Sin[t], Cos[t]};
```

This gives

```
{z1[t], z2[t]}
```

> ```
> {Piecewise[{{Sin[t], Sin[t] > Cos[t]}}, 0], Piecewise[{{Cos[t], Sin[t] > Cos[t]}}, 0]}
> ```

Comment: Or just `{z1[t_], z2[t_]} = Piecewise[{{#, Sin[t] > Cos[t]}}] & /@ {Sin[t], Cos[t]};` Check definitions with `Information /@ {z1, z2}`

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what the aim is but you could also:

```
f[t_] := Piecewise[{{{Cos[t], Sin[t]}, Sin[t] > Cos[t]}, {{0, 0}, 
    True}}]
```

Plotting:

```
ParametricPlot[Evaluate[f[t]], {t, 0, 2 Pi}, Exclusions -> None]
```

[image]